# How to render decoded HTML in a (i.e. a <br>) in GridView cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, newline

I'm binding a GridView to an LINQ query. Some of the fields in the objects created by the LINQ statement are strings, and need to contain new lines.

Apparently, GridView HTML-encodes everything in each cell, so I can't insert a <br /> to create a new line within a cell.

How do I tell GridView not to HTML encode the contents of cells?

Maybe I should use a different control instead?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Can you subscribe to the RowDataBound event?  If you can, you can run:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
  string decodedText = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(e.Row.Cells[0].Text);
  e.Row.Cells[0].Text = decodedText;
}
```

Comment: One of the advantages of this method over setting `HtmlEncode` property on the `BoundField` to `false` is that you can add HTML tags around the text and still use the HTML encoding of the data. For instance,

`e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "<span>" + e.Row.Cells[0].Text + "</span>";`

Answer (score 51):

What about setting the [`HtmlEncode` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.htmlencode.aspx) to `false`? To me, this is much simpler.

```asp
<asp:BoundField DataField="MyColumn" HtmlEncode="False" />
```

Comment: Agreed. This is much much easier.

Comment: At my end, its adding a new column with blank header and original one is still there. so its of no use...

Comment: Found a thing that you also need to set `autogeneratecolumns="false"` attribute to GridView. But in this case you need to add `<asp:BoundField>` for each database field inside `<column>` sub-tag of GridView control.

Answer (score 4):

Are normal newlines preserved in output? If so, you can send the newlines, and use the css style `white-space: pre`, which would preserve newlines, spaces and tabs.

Comment: Great, this helped me out, avoiding string-replacements in code.

Comment: nice solution, i didn't expect this easy solution

Answer (score 4):

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string decodedText = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(e.Row.Cells[i].Text);
            e.Row.Cells[i].Text = decodedText;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got around this by first inserting the data into my sql-server table from a multi-line textbox using

```
   replace (txt = Replace(txt, vbCrLf,"<br />"))
```

Then I used Ray Booysen's solution to return it to my gridview:

```
 Protected Sub grdHist_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles grdHist.RowDataBound

      Dim col1 As String = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(e.Row.Cells(2).Text)

      e.Row.Cells(2).Text = col1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Booysen's answer works but only for one column.  If you run a loop in the RowDataBound event, you can substitute a variable for the [0] and have this work on each column if you want.  Here's what I did:

```
protected void gridCart_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string decode = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(e.Row.Cells[i].Text);
            e.Row.Cells[i].Text = decode;
        }
    }
}
```

Mine is deliberately started at 1 because of my data, but obviously it will work with whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void gvHead_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
  for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++) 
    e.Row.Cells[i].Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(e.Row.Cells[i].Text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind to the the DataBoundGrid event and change the Rendering for the columns you want to render HTML code.

```
public event EventHandler DataBoundGrid {
  add { ctlOverviewGridView.DataBound += value; }
  remove { ctlOverviewGridView.DataBound -= value; }
}

ctlOverview.DataBoundGrid += (sender, args) => {
  ((sender as ASPxGridView).Columns["YourColumnName"] as GridViewDataTextColumn).PropertiesTextEdit.EncodeHtml = false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`@Ray Booysen` answers is right but in some cases HtmlDecode() can't handle your problem. you can use UrlDecode() instead of HtmlDecode().

here is another solution:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
  string decodedText = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(e.Row.Cells[0].Text);
  e.Row.Cells[0].Text = decodedText;
}
```