# Is there a way to insert Html into a gridview row?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, gridview

Using aspnet 3.5, c# - Is there a way to insert Html into a gridview row?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431840/how-to-render-decoded-html-in-a-i-e-a-br-in-gridview-cell . Aaron Daniels' answer of setting the HtmlDecode property of a BoundColumn worked well for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes.  Use the `TemplateField`, and then type your html directly into the markup.  If the html is suppose to be dynamically created I would use a `Literal` instead of a `Label`.

```
<asp:GridView id="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField headertext="Column1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <br />
                <h1>
                    <%# Eval ("DataColumnName") %>
                </h1>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField headertext="Column2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Literal id="Literal1" runat="server" text='<%# Eval ("DataColumnName2") %>'></asp:Literal>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. So did Steven's answer. Both are easy solutions.

Comment: Am going with this solution. Not hardcoding column position into my code and also consistent with the other ways I am dynamically populating my GridView:                                                      

Literal theLit = (Literal)r.FindControl("Literal1"); 
                                                              theLit.Text=@"<b>Make this bold</b>";

Answer (score 3):

Simply modify the `Text` property of a cell.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but you should be able to add a Label control to the GridView cell.  Then write your HTML to the Label's Text property.  The Label should render the HTML.

Comment: Had tried this: it just prints out the html as text, is : <b>Make this bold</> with the view source using the asci chars for < and > and /

Comment: This is not a good approach. And also a Label wraps the text property values between a <span> tag.

Comment: @Lansey , I tried it right after I posted and it worked for me.  I used "<b>hey</b> hey"  and the first hey was bolded and the second was not.