# Render HTML tags in GridView Cell

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview and i want to insert inside a cell a Panel in which inside i want to render html tags. Instead i see in the text the html tags. Any ideas?.

```
   protected void grdThreat_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Panel mainPanel = new Panel(); 
        mainPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(e.Row.Cells[4].Text)); 
            e.Row.Cells[4].Controls.Add(mainPanel);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I think you may want an anchor tag (HyperLink) instead of a LiteralControl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify the Text property of the cell and then it should work. Currently it is just pasting as text.

also see [How to render decoded HTML in a (i.e. a <br>) in GridView cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431840/how-to-render-decoded-html-in-a-i-e-a-br-in-gridview-cell)

Answer (score 4):

set the HtmlEncode property to false in the GridViews bound field that contains the HTML

Comment: This is what solved my problem for my old project, thanks! (3y later haha)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use HttpUtility.HtmlDecode in System.Net nameSpace. I did not test it but it you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Hyperlink instead of Literal control..